# How do I display child footer of a repeater if the child repeater is empty?

Tags: asp.net

I have two repeaters nested in my application which is working fine. I would love to display the footer if the child repeater is empty. Due to my code my long html, i will just drop a sample of what my html looks like and post my full code for better understanding. Everything works fine though unless when the child repeater is empty i want to display the footer message

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ProductRepeater" runat="server"           OnItemDataBound="ProductRepeater_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
    <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%#Eval("Name")%>
      </td>
    <tr>
    </table>
    <pre>
    <asp:Repeater ID="ChildRepeater" runat="server">
      <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <%#Eval("Description")%>
            <td>
          </tr>
        <table>
        </itemTemplate>
      <FooterTemplate>
      <div>
        <h5>
          <asp:Label ID="lblDefaultMessage" runat="server" Text="This is empty. " Visible="false" ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="Large">
          </asp:Label>
        </h5>
      </div>
    </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    </pre>
    </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>


    <protected void ProductRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        string category = "Value"
        Repeater rptRelated = e.Item.FindControl("ChildRepeater") as Repeater;
        rptRelated.DataSource = getChild(category);
        rptRelated.DataBind();
        if (rptRelated.Items.Count < 1)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
            {
                Label lblDefaultMessage = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblDefaultMessage");
                lblDefaultMessage.Visible = true;

            } 
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find Repeater like:

```
// find Child Repeater
Control ctrl = (sender) as Control;
Repeater rptRelated = ctrl.Parent.NamingContainer as Repeater;
```

And Find control from Repeater's Footer like:

```
Label lblDefaultMessage = 
  (Label)rptRelated.Controls[rptRelated.Controls.Count-1].FindControl("lblDefaultMessage");
```

Add this into child Repeater's `OnItemDataBound` event instead of parent.

```
protected void ChildRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    Control ctrl = (sender) as Control;
    Repeater rptRelated = ctrl.Parent.NamingContainer as Repeater;
    if (rptRelated.Items.Count < 1)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Footer)
        {
            Label lblDefaultMessage = (Label)rptRelated.Controls[rptRelated.Controls.Count-1].FindControl("lblDefaultMessage");
            lblDefaultMessage.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Event is:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ChildRepeater" runat="server" 
              OnItemDataBound="ChildRepeater_ItemDataBound">
```

Comment: i wont be able to access rptRelated.Items.Count in the child repeater

Comment: it also throws a system.nullReference exception

Comment: on which line you exception is.

Comment: if (rptRelated.Items.Count < 1) line

Comment: you have to find child repeater `rptRelated` and check it

Comment: This is how i'm finding the child repeater Repeater rpt = e.Item.FindControl("ChildRepeater") as Repeater;

Answer (score 0):

**Repeater** has no **EmptyDataTemplate** like **GridView**.
You should place your footer content next to **Repeater** and change your "databinding" code like this:

```
Repeater rptRelated = e.Item.FindControl("ChildRepeater") as Repeater;
Label lblDefaultMessage = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblDefaultMessage");    
var ds = getChild(category);
lblDefaultMessage.Visible = ds != null && ds.Rows.Count != 0;
if (rptRelated != null)
{
  rptRelated.DataSource = ds;
  rptRelated.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: the getChild() method returns a DataTable so i can't seem to access ds.Any() from it

Comment: You can use ds.Rows.Count != 0 instead